# Tablas con campos dinámicos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, diseño, tablas, tabla-dinámica

estaba practicando diseño de base de datos y se me ocurrió hacer lo siguiente:

una base de datos para una aplicación en la que se puedan agregar animales y definir para ellos una serie de etiquetas para catalogarlos (características, disculpen el error ortográfico en la imagen), y también definir una cantidad de animales para determinada combinación de etiquetas(características, en la imagen).

Le estuve dando vueltas en mi cabeza, pero la verdad siento que me falta algo por aprender para ver una solución clara.

Me gustaría que me ayudaran con eso y si me pudieran recomendar material de estudio muchísimo mejor, de antemano mil gracias.

[image: Tabla de ejemplo]

Comment: Lo último es basado en opiniones recomiendo quitarlo de la pregunta, además lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

podrías aplicar 2 tablas y 1 vista...

Tabla animales:

- id
- nombre

Tabla animal

- id
- id_animal **[FK]**
- cuerpo
- tamaño
- tono_color

Vista

```
SELECT 
T1.id,
T1.nombre,
T2.cuerpo,
T2.tamaño,
T2.tono_color,
COUNT(T1.nombre AND T2.cuerpo AND T2.tamaño AND T2.tono_color) AS cantidad
FROM animales AS T1
INNER JOIN animal AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.id_animal
GROUP BY T1.nombre,T2.cuerpo,T2.tamaño,T2.tono_color;
```

Comment: es una buena solución, el detalle está en que las características como cuerpo, tamaño y tono color deben ser dinámicas, es decir, poder agregar características nuevas después como, por ejemplo, color de ojos.

Tal vez si guardo por característica la cantidad y después hago un análisis utilizando diagramas de Venn para hallar intersecciones..